# Increasing the Lifespan of OTP Codes in C# Using PureOtp Library

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nuget-package, totp

I'm currently working on implementing OTP (One-Time Password) functionality in C# using the PureOtp library available on GitHub [PureOtp](https://github.com/Coinigy/PureOtp). However, I'm facing an issue with the lifespan of the the codes seem to last only around 30 seconds. I'm looking for suggestions on how to increase this lifespan.

Here's the snippet of the code I'm using:generated OTP codes.

```
string? secret = "mysecretkey";
var totp = new Totp(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));

RETRY:
var otpCode = totp.ComputeTotp();
Console.WriteLine(otpCode);

var userInputOtp = Console.ReadLine();
var isGood = totp.VerifyTotp(userInputOtp, out var timeStepMatched, VerificationWindow.RfcSpecifiedNetworkDelay);

if (isGood)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Secret: " + secret + " Code: " + otpCode + " Result: passed");
    Console.ResetColor();
}
else
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("Secret: " + secret + " Code: " + otpCode + " Result: failed");
    Console.ResetColor();
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Press 'r' key to run again, press 'w' to wait 30 seconds for new code before running again");

var cres = Console.ReadKey();
Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 2);
Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);

switch (cres.KeyChar)
{
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        Console.Write("RETRYING" + new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - 8));
        goto RETRY;
    case 'W':
    case 'w':
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        Console.Write("RETRYING in 30 seconds" + new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - 22));
        Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
        Console.Write("20 seconds");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
        Console.Write("10 seconds");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
        Console.Write("RETRYING" + new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - 8));
        Console.WriteLine();
        goto RETRY;
}
```

Any insights on how I can extend the validity period of these OTP codes beyond 30 seconds would be greatly appreciated
Additionally, if you could provide more details on how the OTP code works internally or suggest alternative approaches for managing OTP lifespans effectively, it would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

I expecting to find a straightforward method within the PureOtp library to customize the lifespan of OTP codes

Comment: How hard have you looked? It took my like 20 seconds to observe that the `Totp` constructor can accept multiple parameters

Comment: Thank you, Damien_The_Unbeliever, for your reply. I'm also looking into the TOTP constructor, but I'm still quite confused. Could you please provide me with your suggestion?

Comment: You can't quite clearly see there is a `step` parameter, for the number of seconds https://github.com/Coinigy/PureOtp/blob/master/PureOtp/Totp.cs#L29 Do note that 30 seconds is industry standard, they certainly shouldn't be longer than 5 minutes (say if your sending them by email/SMS). Are you really still using C# 3.0?

Comment: Thank you, Charlieface, for your reply. I realized I used the wrong tag; it should reflect the current version of C# instead of 3.0. I'll change the tag shortly. Since I'm not very familiar with Stack Overflow, I appreciate your notice. I'll try changing the step of the TOTP and will let you know the result.